# How fast can you split a set of numbers into 2 sets, where the difference of each sum is maximized

Tags: optimization, algorithms

How fast can you perform this task?

More specifically, if there is a set of 2n elements, how fast could you split those elements into two groups of n elements where the sum of each group is of maximum difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the median and split the set into those above and below the median. Using [median of medians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) you can (almost always) find the median in linear time.  Splitting he set is also linear, so you can (almost always) do it in linear time.  The almost comes if you continue to choose bad pivots.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question, but don't you sort them and split them in the middle? The answer presumably then, is "as quickly as you can sort them".

Comment: But they don't technically need to be sorted. Because the order does not matter. All that matters is that one group has "small" numbers and one has the "big" numbers." Does that make it faster? Or do you think you still need to sort.

Comment: I think the other answer covers this point.